# how to search entire array and then return 1 thing

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm struggling to get my code to do what I want. I have an array list containing details of bicycles age, model, hire number, and manufacturer. In that list i want to find the bicycle with the matching hire number and update its age. If no match is found i want to print 'no matching bicycle found'. My issue here is i only want that message to be printed once but whenever I run the program it's printed multiple times. I would like to find a way to check the entire list and then if there is no matching hire number print 'no matching bicycle found' once.

```
public void updateAge(int hireNumber, int newAge) {
    ArrayList<Bicycle> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Bicycle bicycle : bicycles){
       if (bicycle.getHireNumber()!=(hireNumber)){
            System.out.println("No matching bicycle found.");
       } else {
            bicycle.setAge(newAge);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `isFound` flag and set to `true` if the condition `bicycle.getHireNumber() == hireNumber` is met as shown below:

```
 ArrayList<Bicycle> output = new ArrayList<>();
 boolean isFound = false;

 for(Bicycle bicycle : bicycles){
     if (bicycle.getHireNumber() == hireNumber) {
          isFound = true;
          bicycle.setAge(newAge);
          return;//match found, so break & return
     }
  }

 //now check isFound is true, if not print it (only once)
 if(!isFound) {
    System.out.println("No matching bicycle found.");
 }
```

Comment: could even just return and remove the `if` check

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks, I updated to `return` instead of `break`